Using Angular Resource API together with Signals and multiple Requests
i have setup where i fire a request to the backend and provide with the request the query params pageSize and pageIndex to the backend. The Page parameters are controlled by a PageEvent.
So in the old world that looks like
  reloading: boolean = false
  pageSize: number = 20
  pageIndex: number = 0
  totalSize: number = 0
  accounts: AccountSearchEntry[] = []

  request = new AccountSearchRequest('')

  search() {
    this.reload(0, this.pageSize)
  }

  private reload(page: number, size: number) {
    if (this.reloading) return
    this.reloading = true
    this.searchService.searchAccounts(this.request, page, size).subscribe(
      {
        next: value => this.handleData(value),
        error: e => this.handleError(e)
      }
    )
  }


  private handleData(response: AccountSearchResponse) {
    let p = response.result
    this.accounts = p.content
    this.pageSize = p.pageable.size
    this.pageIndex = p.pageable.number
    this.totalSize = p.totalSize
    this.reloading = false
  }

So far so good. No i want to switch to signals.
So i changed it like that.
pageSize = signal<number>(20)
  pageIndex = signal<number>(0)
  totalSize = signal<number>(0)
  fullTextSearch = signal<string>('')

  accountsCriteria = computed(() => ({
    request: new AccountSearchRequest(this.fullTextSearch()),
    pageSize: this.pageSize(),
    pageIndex: this.pageIndex()
  }))
  
  accountsResource = resource({
    request: this.accountsCriteria,
    loader: (param) => {
      return toPromise(this.searchService.searchAccounts(param.request.request, param.request.pageIndex, param.request.pageSize), param.abortSignal)
    }
  });

  reloading = this.accountsResource.isLoading
  accounts = computed(() => this.accountsResource.value ?? [])

the problem comes if i want so reset the page index if i set the fullTextSearch
like so
  setFullTextSearch(val: string) {
    this.pageIndex.set(0)
    this.fullTextSearch.set(val)
  }

because that fires two requests to the backend, what i do not want.
Also handling the PageEvent is now difficult
  handlePageEvent(event: PageEvent) {
    // this.reload(event.pageIndex, event.pageSize)
    this.pageIndex.set(event.pageIndex)
    this.pageSize.set(event.pageSize)
  }

I had the idea to introduce a second criteria for the page and one for the request, but that seems not practival eigher. Also i like to update the pageSize and the pageIndex from both sides. If there is a change on the UI the page size should change and a request will be fired to the backend. But if the backend returns a value, the page size is overwritten with the data provided by the backend.
Any help appreciated
Thx Oli

Are you sure setFullTextSearch triggers 2 requests ?

i assumed it .. do you know more? @MatthieuRiegler

There is no reason for the loader to fire mutiple times besides have very distinct (in time) signal changes.

okay .. did not know that .. thank you
